# WPF using one VIewModel to manipulate TextBoxes in two seperate windows

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, window

I am having a problem with binding data. I'd like to bind text of TextBox which is in MainWindow to another TextBox which is in ChildWindow. While being in MainWindow, user can input a string into that TextBox. ChildWindow will be only displaying some data. I've managed to bind the TextBox from MainWIndow and I can see that while debugging it hits MainWindowViewModel, However there's no effect on the ChildWindow.

My App.xaml.cs looks like this:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        var window = new MainWindow() { DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel() };
        window.Show();

        base.OnStartup(e);
    }
}
```

then MainWIndow creates an instance of ChildWindow and they both use same ViewModel as below:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        var viewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();
        ChildWindow childWindow = new ChildWindow();
        childWindow.DataContext = viewModel;
        childWindow.Show();
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = viewModel;
    }
}
```

MainWindowViewModel:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public string _firstTeamName { get; set; }
    public string FirstTeamName
    {
        get { return _firstTeamName; }
        set
        {
            _firstTeamName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FirstTeamName));
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModelBase:

```
public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Binding in MainWindow.xaml:

```
<TextBox x:Name ="firstTeam"  Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text ="{Binding FirstTeamName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Binding in ChildWindow.xaml:

```
<TextBlock Text ="{Binding FirstTeamName}" FontSize="24"></TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is to set the `MainWindow.DataContext` twice.

1. Inside the contructor of `MainWindow`
2. In `App.OnStartUp` with `var window = new MainWindow() { DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel() };`

What does happen here?

- `new MainWindow()` will call the constructor and set the `DataContext` of `MainWindow` and `ChildWindow` to the same instance of `MainWindowViewModel`.
- `{ DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel() }` will overwrite the `DataContext` of `MainWindow` with a new instance of `MainWindowViewModel`.

Now the two windows have two different instances of the ViewModel and will not work as expected.

This should fix it

```cs
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        var window = new MainWindow() 
        { 
            // DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel() 
        };
        window.Show();

        base.OnStartup(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks, you're totally right. It works correctly now. :)